# which are the ways to find new files in a server location

Tags: linux, find

I'm trying to find new file(s) created, copied, moved or modified in latest hour in a linux server location `/home/user/`.

I would like to know if the following command is the best way covering all situations (created, copied, moved or modified) or if this command does not cover all situations and I may lose some files from my search.
I would exclude from the search result all files which are simply executed or read/accessed.

```
find /home/user/ -type f -newermt '-3600 seconds' -printf "%T+ %p\n"
```

Comment: Ciao. With `-newerXY` you need a reference file, in your case to be updated each time. You may want to give it a look to `rsync` too, with a dry run... It remains open the problem of how you want to deal with the links (hard and symbolic). Another tool often used for the ftp sites was to create a `ls-Rt` file... It depends what you need to do with the output of your search; i.e. it is never a good idea to go to parse the output of `ls`... (due to the fact that, i.e., a newline can be a valid char for a file name, not rare in pdf files with name taken from the title).

Comment: `created, copied, moved or modified` would mean `-newermc`, though I've never checked to if it includes "created".  (I assume it would, since even creating a file touches  the inode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple: testing file time properties

If I would strictly stick to the question then I would use

```
find /home/user/ -type f -cmin -60
```

I tested this.  The commands also identifies when a file was moved inside the directory.
File accesses are not reported by this command.

## Better: watching events

However, I guess that you want to do something when there was an event.  In this case you may want to look into [`iwatch`](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html) which relies on `inotify`.
It will trigger on system events and allow you to act on an event as soon as it happens.
You'll not miss out on files that appeared only temporarily.

This is a '/etc/iwatch/iwatch.xml' file that I changed slightly from the one I actually use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE config SYSTEM "/etc/iwatch/iwatch.dtd" >
<config>
  <guard email="root@localhost" name="IWatch"/>
  <watchlist>
    <title>Document signing</title>
    <contactpoint email="root@localhost" name="Administrator"/>
    <path type="recursive" syslog="on" alert="off" events="close_write" exec="sudo -u sign /home/sign/signpdf %f 'Non-modification et Origine du do
cument' >> /home/sign/pdf.log 2>/home/sign/pdf2.log">/home/sign/documents</path>
  </watchlist>
</config>
```

It's more complex than using 'find', but it is also more fine-grained.  In the above, the command is only executed on a 'close_write'.  So the risk of manipulating a file that is still being written is reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with comment above, rsync may be better solution, depending on what you are trying to accomplish with the file list.  Here's a good answer that covers a lot of ground, including the comments
https://serverfault.com/a/618740

```
rsync -zaic src/ dest/ | grep '^?c' | cut -d' ' -f2 --dry-run
```

would only list the modified files (different checksum)

Comment: I suppose `--dry-run` goes _hand in hand_ with `rsync` before the pipe ... however, there are some problems to parse and use the output, _ls-like_, in successive steps... How you stated it depends on what OP is trying to accomplish.